# Prove that $Z = \frac{X_1}{X_2}$, has an F-distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, random-variable, density-function, f-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2$ be independent random variables following density law $f(x) = e^{-x} , 0 < x < \infty$, Show that
$Z = \frac{X_1}{X_2}$, has an F-distribution.
I thought of solving this by solving for the mgf of $Z$ but then I remembered that mgf of F-distribution doesn't exist, so I couldn't do it that way. How to approach questions like these in general?

Comment: Please add a [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag. Also what made you add 'jacobian' tag?

Comment: I add the jocobian tag because i thought there is going to be jacobian transformation involved in the proof.

Comment: Maybe try $f_Z(z)=\int_0^\infty f_{Z|X_2=x_2}(z)f_{X_2}(x_2)dx_2$ (the law of total probability).

Comment: @JarleTufto $f_{Z|X_2 = x_2} = \frac{f(Z|X_2 = x_2)}{f(X_2 = x_2)}$. How do I find $f(Z|X_2 = x_2)$?

Comment: Conditional on $X_2$, $Z$ is equal to $X_1$ times a constant so it has an exponential distribution (or gamma in the general case).

Comment: How do you define or characterize an F distribution?  For many, it is *defined* as the ratio of two independent chi-squared variables (suitably scaled).  If that's the case for you, simply observe that $f$ is the density law of a scaled $\chi^2(2)$ variable.  As far as "questions like these," what do you mean by that? Questions for homework? Questions about algebraic combinations of random variables? About transformations? About ratios of independent variables? About distributions related to the Normal distribution? About mgfs?

Comment: @whuber Sorry I didn't specify. I meant questions about algebraic combinations of random variables.

Comment: There are many general techniques, which makes that question a little too broad to be answerable in this forum.

Answer (score 6):

Let's not try to generalize about "questions like these,"
but to answer the specific question at hand, using the definition of an F-distribution in terms of chi-squared distributions, as mentioned in a Comment by @whuber.
[While moment generating functions and bivariate
transformations with Jacobians are often useful, they
are not needed in this particular problem.]

$\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=2)\equiv\mathsf{Exp}(\mathrm{rate}=1/2).$
So multiply the exponential random variable $X_1$ in the numerator by a constant $c$ so that $cX_1 \sim 
\mathsf{Chisq}(2).$ Then $\frac{X_1}{X_2}=\frac{cX_1/2}{cX_2/2}\sim \mathsf{F}(2,2).$

This can be illustrated by a simulation in R.

```
set.seed(116)
x1 = rexp(10^6);  x2 = rexp(10^6)
f = x1/x2
summary(f)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
  0.00083   0.31794   1.11853   6.20911   3.21720 201.36394
```

$\mathsf{F}(2,2)$ is a highly skewed distribution. For clarity, the histogram of simulated values below omits a (relatively) few observations beyond 100. The red curve is the density function of $\mathsf{F}(2,2).$

[image]

```
hist(f[f<100], prob=2, br=100, ylim=c(0,.5),
     col="skyblue2", main="F(2,2)")
 curve(df(x,2,2), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```